# how to gather number of categories of each row to one row and count each one of the categories

Tags: sql, join, select, group-by, count

I want to know how from 2 rows to make 1 row of each category and also count each one of the categories

table clothes for example:

| clothes1 | clothes2 |
| --- | --- |
| shirt | pants |
| shirt | Null |
| dress | shirt |
| Socks | pants |

I need a query to look like this.(is it possible without a new table?). This should be the result:

| clothes | count |
| --- | --- |
| shirt | 50 |
| socks | 30 |
| pants | 20 |
| dress | 10 |

Do I need to use row_number() over (partition) or can I use group by somehow? Or is there another way? And also I need to show top 3.

Thank you!

Comment: Please tag single RDBMS, because MySQL <> SQL Server.

Comment: How did you get count column?

Comment: D-Shih I need to count all the columns together for each category (I have 5 columns of clothes, but here I gave an example for 2 columns)

Answer (score 1):

Take a union of the two columns and then aggregate:

```sql
SELECT clothes, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM
(
    SELECT clothes1 AS clothes FROM clothes
    UNION ALL
    SELECT clothes2 FROM clothes
) t
GROUP BY clothes;
```

Comment: I don't need to count everything but just the clothes 1 and clothes 2 (I have another coloumns like id, brand and etc) . what is t?

Comment: @d12 `t` is an alias.  You have edited your question since I initially answered.